# Having trouble with assigning a PHP echo varible to document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, getelementbyid

**This works:** note-($i = 1)

```
  document.getElementById("range1").setAttribute("value", javascript_array[<?php echo $j++; ?>]);</script>     
  <p><input type="text" name="range<?php echo $i; ?>" id="range<?php echo $i; ?>" />
```

**This does not work:**
document.getElementById("range").setAttribute("value", javascript_array[]);
input type="text" name="range" id="range" />

If I replace "range1" with "range" /not working/

I have read allot and tried several options (+, &, move the "" around) to add  to that location but will not work. If I put in "range1" works but not "range".  I have the PHP echo in other locations and it works: "value",.., <input type.. name=, id="range<?...

I tried this too and didn't work:
var rangex = "range" + ;
alert(rangex);

```
    document.getElementById(rangex).setAttribute("value", javascript_array[<?php echo $j++; ?>]);</script>     
    <p><input type="text" name="range<?php echo $i; ?>" id="range<?php echo $i; ?>" />
```

The alert does come up with "range1" but still will not work. Not sure why StackOF is cutting off the "does not work code"?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Does your JS is generated as you need this? We cannot know where's the problem, as you don't specify it. First of all get the whole HTML/JS generated by PHP, save as **static** HTML file and make sure, that it works and/or find bugs and fix them. When you'll have static code working consider how to fix PHP and then it will be easier to correct PHP and/or add some details about yor problem to this question.

Comment: It works with "range1" but not with "range"<?php echo $i; ?>. There is not much to the code. I'm just working on this part. Also the "range"<?php echo $i; ?> is working on other lines and at the end with Value.

Comment: Once again - validate the code generated by PHP, i.e. in browser use inspector tools to inspect the element or just display whole source of the page. what is showing in generated HTML in the place where in PHP you have `range<?php echo $i; ?>` just paste this part by common copying it from browser.

Comment: Sorry the question looks weird but StackOF is cutting off <?php echo $i; ?> part for some reason?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Looking with the inspector it shows:  document.getElementById("range"1)

Comment: so you need to change `"range"<?php echo $i; ?>` to `"range<?php echo $i; ?>"`. Keep checking mistakes in the result code in inspector while you'll remove all if it won't work still update your question with details.

Comment: I tried that and didn't work got error:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Again: debug and run your static code again, remove all bugs and fix PHP to generate valid HTML and JS we are **NOT** able to do it remotely for you.

Comment: I had to switch the lines(above and below) and everything is working.